# count the day between two dates without duplication

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have following table

```
  id      date  
------- + ---------      
  1      10-01-2014  
  2      10-01-2014  
  3      15-01-2014  
  4      15-01-2014  
  5      20-01-2014  
  6      30-01-2014  
  7      03-02-2014  
  8      12-02-2014  
  9      12-02-2014 
  10     19-02-2014  
  11     19-02-2014
```

My table name is : attendance . I want to calculate the number of dates in Between `01-01-2014 to 20-02-2014` without repetiton.

Following is my query for this :

```
SELECT distinct(todaydate) FROM attendance WHERE  todaydate between '01-02-2014' and '24-02-2014'
```

its working but the answer is wrong. 
Any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT distinct(todaydate) FROM attendance WHERE todaydate between '01-02-2014' and '24-02-2014' group by date`

Comment: You need to convert your string dates to MySQL and then use BETWEEN for comparision.

Comment: What is data type of field date in your table as provided format is not mysql date format.. i think columns name is date not todaydate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`date`) AS date
FROM attendance
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)>UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01-01-2014') 
      AND
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)<UNIX_TIMESTAMP('24-02-2014')
```

OR

```
SELECT date
FROM attendance
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)>UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01-01-2014') 
      AND
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)<UNIX_TIMESTAMP('24-02-2014')  
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

In question you want to calculate dates in between 01-01-2014 to 20-02-2014
but in query you have mentioned some other date.

So actual query will be:

```
SELECT distinct(todaydate) 
FROM attendance 
WHERE  todaydate between '01-01-2014' and '24-02-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your dates are string** you need to convert them into **MySQL Date** using `STR_TO_DATE`

Try like

```
SELECT distinct
    (STR_TO_DATE(todaydate, '%d-%m-%Y')) as todaydate
FROM
    attendance
WHERE
    todaydate between STR_TO_DATE('01-02-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('24-02-2014', '%d-%m-%Y');
```